# How can I get the <see langword=> tag to use C# keywords rather than VB keywords?

Tags: sandcastle, code-documentation

I'm documenting C# code using XML and *Sandcastle Help File Builder* to generate *HtmlHelp1* help files. I've set the `SyntaxFilters` property on the Sandcastle project to `CSharp` as I only want to generate code syntax relevant to C#.

I'm making use of the `<see langword="[langword]" />`, such as the the following:

```
<see langword="null" />
<see langword="true" />
<see langword="false" />
```

As I had set the `SyntaxFilters` property to `CSharp` I was expecting the above tags to be converted to equivalent C# keywords, as follows:

```
null
true
false
```

Instead they are being converted to the equivalent keyword for Visual Basic, as follows:

```
Nothing
True
False
```

Is there a way to these tags to replaced with the appropriate C# keywords rather than Visual Basic keywords or shall I not use the see tag at all?

Comment: Does this problem still occur or was it fixed meanwhile?

Comment: Isn't there a configuration in the Sandcastle project like what language you want the declarations to be generated in? I know that if you select a language in such case, these words also change to correspond the selected language, and will remain like that through all the pages, until the next change.